# My android app is compatible with 0 devices in PlayStore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

My app is not compatible on any mobile device. Installs with no problem from the APK file, it works perfectly, but for some reason Google Play doesn't list it. Any suggestions.

I thinks that the problem isn't in the manifest because I upload with the same app without permission and, the problem was appeared again.

Comment: i smiled when i saw this question..

Comment: Did you look at the final manifest generated by Android Studio? It's in the build directory. Something like `app/build/intermediates/manifests/...` in a standard project structure.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your manifest...

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="14"    
          />
```

You can change the api levels

Comment: I deleted that sentences because android studio show this message "this targetsdkversion is not used it is always overridden by the value specific in gradle" and don't work

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, I used a own library I did in Eclipse as a jar, but even in devices my app worked well in the playstore was wrong. I solved that problem creating my library as a module in Android Studio.